# Tabindex using only css?

Tags: css, tabindex

I was asked to help with accessibility on a website. Problem is that website is hosted at wordpress.com so I don't have access to HTML code and I can only use custom CSS. Biggest problem with keyboard accessibility is that using tab you end up in sticky header menu which does not open. So is there any solution using only CSS to skip that sticky header menu? With HTML I have used "tabindex -1". Is there any solutions using only CSS or should I inform my friend to migrate away from wordpress.com to some other hosting service? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I am aware that is not possible *in pure CSS*. Is custom JS an option? Or creating a custom, derived theme from the current theme?

Comment: If JS can be executed in custom CSS "box" that WP Nikau theme provides then yes but I kinda doubt that. Making custom changes seems to very challenging but maybe that is the point of those themes, easy to setup hard to break. Thank you for your help I will tell him to consider some other hosting option/theme.

Comment: You should check out how to create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) in Wordpress.